# Is there a way I can implement the "JpegCoefficientFilter" to extract the histogram features on Python?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, weka, imagefilter

I have used weka as part of my image classification project. I have determined the best combination of image filter and classifier.

However there is limited information online on the JpegCoefficientFilter image filter. Does anyone know how I can approach this problem?

Links that may help:

https://github.com/mmayo888/ImageFilter  (documentation/code for the imagefilters weka package)
https://sourceforge.net/projects/weka/   (weka download)

Answer (score 0):

The **imageFilter** Weka package uses the [LIRE](https://github.com/dermotte/LIRE) library under the hood (version 0.9.5) to generate the features. JpegCoefficientFilter itself uses the [JpegCoefficientHistogram](https://github.com/dermotte/LIRE/blob/version0.9.5/src/main/java/net/semanticmetadata/lire/imageanalysis/JpegCoefficientHistogram.java) class (which you can see when you look at the source code).

Comment: That's sort of my question. Is there a way to implement the JpegCoefficientHistogram class easily from python?

Comment: Just convert the Java class that I linked into Python. The entry point is the method `extract(BufferedImage bimg)` (`BufferedImage` is Java's way of representing images) and then follow the relevant calls.